# change_column_null for existing column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I'm attempting to change the `nil` possibility of a boolean attribute on the existing column `:access_titles` on the `:profiles` table. That column exists because of this migration:

```
class AddAccessItemsToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :profiles, :access_items, :boolean, :default => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :profiles, :access_items, :boolean, :default => nil
  end
end
```

To change `nil`, I tried generating a migration as I always have:

```
rails g migration ChangeColumnNull :profiles :access_items :null => false
```

But that did nothing, so I did a standalone migration:

```
rails g migration AddChangeColumnNullToAccessItems
```

And within that I added:

```
class AddChangeColumnNullToAccessItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, :boolean, false
  end

  def self.down
    change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, :boolean, true
  end
end
```

I then ran `rake db:migrate`, restarted my server and saw no changes. So I tried:

```
class AddChangeColumnNullToAccessItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, false
  end

  def self.down
    change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, true
  end
end
```

Then did the same thing: `rake db:migrate`, restarted the server, and nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong? I was hoping to only have the boolean value of `:access_items` be true and false without having to dump the database.

**UPDATE:** Trying `change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, false` I got an error:

```
-- change_column_null(:profiles, :access_items, false)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  column "access_items" contains null values
: ALTER TABLE "profiles" ALTER "access_items" SET NOT NULL
```

So, per the advice below I had to insert `change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, false, true` into my migration.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use:

```
change_column_null :profiles, :access_items, false, 1
```

***The fourth parameter is optional** and allows you to set the default value for the column. This is required when you have nulls in a column and you're setting the null value to `false`.*

Comment: I had to add the fourth column after all. Thanks yet again!

Comment: Didn't know that the fourth parameter was even possible. I would have thought that this occurs so often that it would be required.