# Rails migration file fails - Mysql2::Error: Data truncated for column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've set up a new migration file:

```
class ChangeCourseDefaults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column_null :course_objects, :active, false
    change_column_default :course_objects, :active, 0
  end
end
```

I run it this way on my debian server (rails 4.2.1 ruby 2.1)

```
sudo bundle exec rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20150720095700 RAILS_ENV=test
```

Then I got this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Data truncated for column 'active' at row 1: ALTER TABLE `course_objects` CHANGE `active` `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL/var/www/html/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4..2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `query'
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: is there any record previously which is already null.? please check

Comment: yes there are numberous ones

Comment: yes that is why when this line     `change_column_null :course_objects, :active, false` runs it will check for all values and confirm there should not be any null. and here it crashes. but i guess the answer pasted below will solve your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **[change_column_null](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null)**

```
class ChangeCourseDefaults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :table_name, :column_name, false, 0 # set default as 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I got this error:

undefined method `null' for #<ChangeCourseDefaultsNull:0x00000005be8de0>/var/www/html/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:661:in `block in method_missing'

Comment: replace null with false.

Comment: The [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null) for `change_column_null` say:

"The method accepts an optional fourth argument to replace existing +NULL+s with some other value. Use that one when enabling the constraint if needed, since otherwise those rows would not be valid. Please note the fourth argument does not set a column’s default."

Answer (score 2):

```
class ChangeCourseDefaults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :course_objects, :active, false, 0
  end
end
```

reference: [change_column_null for existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954804/change-column-null-for-existing-column)

Comment: i just added the answer because above has few issues. please accept above answer Felix once it is correct. he has more right.:)